# TreeMap put 100 elements(1MB each) and Heap have only 80 MB memory, behavior in this case?

Tags: java, collections, out-of-memory

Heap space have only 80 MB memory available. We need to put 100 elements(of 1MB each) in TreeMap.

What is the behavior in this case when 80th element is put into map?
How will garbage collection work in this scenario?
what is the effective way to handle such scenario?

Comment: When you have 100 objects of 1MB each, they do not fit into a heap memory of 80MB, whether you try to store them into a `TreeMap` or not. The garbage collector does not do magic, 100MB do not fit into 80MB, period.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit un-clear, since you put `Key` *and* `Value` to a `Map`, not individual elements. I'll assume your Key + Value combined will give you 1MB.

If they indeed have `1MB` each - your memory will blow up a lot faster then even 50 elements that you put into your `TreeMap`, since each object has 2 headers (`12 bytes` combined on typical VM's); there is padding involved + each Key + Value is wrapped into an `Entry` internally that add some overhead too.

GC is not going to be able to help you much, you have limited memory to begin with; your VM is blow up with an `OutOfMemory`. GC will be triggered when you are getting close to the limits (this heavily depends on the GC used and the input parameters), but since there will be not much to clean - it will basically not do much, if anything at all.